# Unity Changes Colors

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a sprite in unity and it is supposed to look like this :[image]

but when I export to unity it looks like this : [image]

Comment: I'm not sure why it's mirrored, but the background is solid because whatever export settings you're using don't have transparency enabled. If you're exporting from another program like photoshop TO Unity, then this is a question for that program. Either way, you need to give a bit more information about what you're using, what settings you've tried, etc.

Comment: no the mirror is because of my code but the problem is that all of the colors in the sprite get messed up, Also the background isn't a problem either

Comment: The hair color turns in to two colors and the blue turns a reddish color and some other things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I'm seeing I'm assuming a few pixels are slightly different in color. The culprit in this likely is the compression.

Find your image asset and change it's `Compression` to either `None` or a higher quality value.

Here's an example using a different image to illustrate the difference:
[image]

On the left side, if you look at the image closely, some of the lines blend together while on the right side they don't - each line has a different color.

Here's the image I used to test the setting:
[image]